# keyerror: 'Date' after Importing from xlsx

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, xlsx

I'm trying to import this short xlsx in jupyter

[image]

with this code

```
import pandas as pd
fields=['Date', 'A', 'C']
df = pd.read_excel('/home/maspis/Scrivania/date_try.xlsx', sheet_name='I1', usecols=fields)
#df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.info()
```

I get this output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Empty DataFrame'
```

Then, when I use pd.to_datetime I get the following

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:
......

KeyError: 'Date'
```

Can you please help me coping with this issue?

Thanks,
G

Comment: Make sure that the `sheet_name=I1` is the right sheet you are reading.

Comment: Thanks Mayank, but I get always the same result, even when I delete the sheet_name='I1' condition.

Comment: Delete `usecols` condition also and see what you get in `df`.

Comment: it works...but I have a huge dataset and I want to use 'usecol'....any suggestion? Please

Comment: You can read the whole excel. Then can take the subset of the dataframe for the columns you actually want. Check the output of `df.columns`.

Comment: the output is   
Index(['Date', 'A', 'C'], dtype='object')

Comment: but I'd lke to avoid reading the whole xlsx...because I got to do that with several files. what's wong for you in using 'usecol'?  is there a Type problem?